# MySql query how to generate this?

Tags: mysql, join

Generate names of employee pairs such that both employees in the pair have the same manager. the table is just: manages (enmployee_name, mgrName).
I was thinking a natural join on itself and then create a table from that with emp1|emp2. But I can't get the syntax figured out.

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and the query you are stuck with.

Comment: Here you have the syntax for SELECT in Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: select * from manages right join on manages; But that doesn't work. I wish there was more information this is a past test question I failed on.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select * from Managers m1
join Managers m2 on m1.ManagerID = m2.ManagerID --same manager
and m1.EmployeeID < m2.EmployeeID --exclude duplicates like Jordan-Pipen and Pipen-Jordan.
```